# Measuring Forward Impedance of a pulsed drive circuit

Tags: impedance, pulse, thyristor

Background:

I recently built a thyristor driving circuit to supply a set number of trigger pulses to my thytratron (tetrode configuration). The spec sheet for the thyratron requires that my driving circuit has a "forward impedance of 50-100 ohms."

Question:
While the circuit is supplying the trigger pulses to the thyratron, how can I measure the forward impedance of the thyristor driving circuit (the device that supplies the pulses)?

Comment: Allow 10% drop with 1k load or 50% at matched load

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Are you saying that there will be a 10% drop in voltage across a 1k ohm resistor when the pulsed supply is connected to the load?

Comment: Ohm's Law says if load is 10x source there will be a 10% drop..  assuming source is 50~100 ohms  a 1k load , you have a voltage divider

Comment: matched load always drops 50%